# Scala Check optional string is null or empty

Tags: java, scala, nullpointerexception, functional-programming, isnull

I am a newbie to Scala and I want to learn how can I add null and empty check on an **optional** string?

```
val myString : Option[String]

if (null != myString) {
  myString
    .filter(localStr=> StringUtils.isEmpty(localStr))
    .foreach(localStr=> builder.queryParam("localStr", localStr))
}
```

Above code works but I want to learn some elegant way of writing same check. Any help is highly appreciated,

thanks

Comment: are you sure that `Option` can be null?

Comment: Generally, when using an `Option[T]`, you shouldn't be doing null checks. The exact purpose of an `Option[T]` is to work on a box which may or may not have a value.

Answer (score 5):

There is a quite convenient way using the `Option` constructor.

```
scala> Option("Hello Worlds !")
res: Option[String] = Some(Hello Worlds !)


scala> Option(null)
res: Option[Null] = None
```

So if you would have list of Strings with possible null values you can use a combination of `Option` and `flatten`:

```
scala> List("Speak", "friend", null, "and", null ,"enter").map(s => Option(s)) .flatten
res: List[String] = List(Speak, friend, and, enter)
```

Answer (score 4):

Pattern matching will help in simplifying your code:

```
myString match {
case Some(s) if(!s.isEmpty) => s.foreach(localStr=> builder.queryParam("localStr", localStr))
case _ => "No String"
}
```

Comment: You can also use "s.nonEmpty" on Strings, instead of "!s.isEmpty".

Answer (score 2):

I guess idiomatic way looks like this:

```
val myString : Option[String] = ...
myString
  .filterNot(StringUtils.isEmpty)
  .foreach(builder.queryParam("localStr", _))
```

Answer (score 1):

Option[String] can store 2 types of value either Some(String) or None so when u dont need to check for null u just check for None with the help of scala match case as follows

```
val myString : Option[String] = Some("ss")

 myString match {
   case Some(str)=>str.filter(localStr=> StringUtils.isEmpty(localStr))
    .foreach(localStr=> builder.queryParam("localStr", localStr))
   case None => //do whatever you want while condition failure
 }
```